# Mouse and Touchpad Glitch

Tags: mouse, touchpad, settings, devices

For Ubuntu 19.10 Users:

When I go into Settings ⇾ Devices and click on “Mouse and Touchpad”, the window starts to flicker and glitch out. It is toggling between the two menu states shown in the attached photos.

[image]

I am unable to edit any of these settings and my only option is to right click and choose Close. I am using a Logitech Mx Master 3 with the receiver dongle along with a Logitech Ego K860 and its receiver dongle. I was not experiencing this issue until recently. Tried uninstalling Solaar with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Please click edit to let us know these facts. 1) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.)? 2) Which release number?  Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Comment: Apologies, Ubuntu 19.10. I just discovered the source of the glitch! If you install "Gnome Tweaks" from the Ubuntu Software store and disable "animations" this has potential to cause abnormal behavior when accessing some menus like "Mouse and Touchpad."

Comment: Please remove SOLUTION from your question and put it into an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when disabling animations with Gnome Tweaks (installed from the Ubuntu Software Center). If abnormal behavior persists try re-enabling animations. This fixed my glitch.